# I18n with Angular JS (jlg-i18n) - Date and currency filters aren't working ( changing $Locale Dynamically)

Tags: angularjs, internationalization, locale, dynamically-generated

I'm trying to use jlg-i18n to i18n my code.The thing is that the strings are translated but the dates and currency are not!

Neither `{{date | date}}` nor {{price | currency}}  seem to work .

It stays like the default locale (the one that was loaded first)

Any ideas? Anyone experiencing this error?

Here is the module on [Github](https://github.com/jlguenego/jlg-i18n)

And my code:

```
<html ng-app="ShoppingList">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Shopping List</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/bootstrap/bootstrap.css">
<style>
    .jumbotron {
        width: 400px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
    .table {
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .form-control {
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
    .selecionado {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
    .negrito {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>
<script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>

<!-- Arquivo de localização referente ao país -->
<script id="locale" src="lib/angular/angular-locale_pt-br.js"></script>

<!--<script src="lib/angular/angular-locale_en-us.js"></script>-->

<!--<script src="lib/angular/angular-locale_fr-fr.js"></script>-->

<!--Caminho do módulo jlg-i18n-->
<script src="bower_components/jlg-i18n/jlg-i18n.min.js"></script>

<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>





<script>
    //Adiciona o módulo ['jlgI18n'] ao módulo Shopping list
    var app = angular.module("ShoppingList",['jlgI18n']);

    //É necessário adicionar ao controlador os serviços '$locale', 'jlgI18nService',
    app.controller("shoppingListCtrl", ['$scope', '$locale', 'jlgI18nService',
        function ($scope, $locale, i18nService) {

            $scope.date = new Date();
        $scope.app = "Shopping list";
        $scope.list = [
            {name: "Chocolate", price: 4.50, date: new Date()},
            {name: "Cookies", price: 3.00, date: new Date()},
            {name: "Potatoes", price: 5.00, date: new Date()}
        ];

        $scope.adicionarContato = function (contato) {
            $scope.contatos.push(angular.copy(contato));
            delete $scope.contato;
        };
        $scope.apagarContatos = function (contatos) {
            $scope.contatos = contatos.filter(function (contato) {
                if (!contato.selecionado) return contato;
            });
        };
        $scope.isContatoSelecionado = function (contatos) {
            return contatos.some(function (contato) {
                return contato.selecionado;
            });
        };

        //Variável que define a localização
        $scope.locale = $locale;

        //Função que altera a localização de acordo com o usuário
        $scope.changeLocale = i18nService.changeLocale;

    }]);

    //Configura o módulo
    app.config(['jlgI18nServiceProvider', function(jlgI18nServiceProvider) {
        jlgI18nServiceProvider.localeDir('../locale');

    }]);


</script>
```

```
<div class="jumbotron">

    <h2>{{app | i18n}}</h2>

    <table ng-show="list.length > 0" class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>{{'Name' | i18n}}</th>
            <th>{{'Price' | i18n}}</th>
            <th>{{'Date' | i18n}}</th>
        </tr>

        <tr ng-repeat="product in list">
            <td>{{product.name | i18n}}</td>
            <td>{{product.price | currency}}</td>
            <td>{{product.date | date }} </td>
        </tr>


        {{date | date:'fullDate'}}

    <p>{{'Locale' | i18n}}: {{locale.id}}</p>
    <div>

        <label ng-repeat="id in ['en-us', 'pt-br', 'fr-fr']">
                <input name="locale_id" type="radio"
                ng-click="changeLocale(id)"
                ng-checked="{{locale.id == id}}"/>
                {{id}}
        </label>
    </div>




</div>
```

my code is a pretty simple code, so i'm almost sure the problem is not it
I appreciate any help and sugestion!

I'm pretty disappointed with this problem, because from the i18n modules for angular this was the simplest one!!

### Update

I already figure out what was wrong, i didn't update the dir of the locale HERE

```
    app.config(['jlgI18nServiceProvider', function(jlgI18nServiceProvider) {
        jlgI18nServiceProvider.localeDir('../locale');

    }]);
```

But strangely, it only solved the Date issue, currency is still not working :/

### Updtae 2

I've figured out why  **jlg-i18n** is not working for currency or number filters! It is not a problem with the module but with angular itself. What happens is that the functions for currency and number are cached from the first locale loaded, so when u change the locale it doesn't make effect. Date works because this function is not stored in cache! 
There is a note on angular js development for fixing this in the future versions! I've found a module for dynamic change of the locale, but is not the right solution for me.

One of the suggested approaches, and the one that i chose is to rewrite the angular functions for currency and number!

Hope it helps someone! :)

Link to the issue of the problem on AngularJS github: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9159

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

I've figured out why JS-i18n is not working for currency or number filters! It is not a problem with the module but with angular itself. What happens is that the functions for currency and number are cached from the first locale loaded, so when u change the locale it doesn't make effect. Date works because this function is not stored in cache! There is a note on angular js development for fixing this in the future versions! I've found a module for dynamic change of the locale that also fixes this problem, but is not the right solution for me.

One of the suggested approaches, and the one that i chose is to rewrite the angular functions for currency and number!

*I realize it is a temporary fix, while the problem is not addressed by Angular's team, and you should too*

Hope it helps someone! :)

If someone wants to use my solution i have it on github (it is a pretty simple project for school, so it is very easy to understand what's being done):
https://github.com/michellebionico/i18n-with-Angular-JS

Link to the issue of the problem on AngularJS github: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9159